# D3 Radar Chart Colors

Tags: d3.js

I am using the D3 radar chart to plot some data:

https://github.com/alangrafu/radar-chart-d3

I am trying to configure the used by the D3 chart using hex codes, like #FFFFFF.

This website:

http://graves.cl/radar-chart-d3/

proposes

```
var mycfg = {
  color: function(){
  c = ['red', 'yellow', 'pink', 'green', 'blue', 'olive', 'aqua', 'cadetblue', 'crimson'];
  m = c.length - 1;
  x = parseInt(Math.random()*100);
  return c[x%m]; //Get a random color
}
}
```

but this returns a random function... I would like something more like:

```
var mycfg = {
  color: function(){
  c = ['red', 'yellow', 'pink', 'green', 'blue', 'olive', 'aqua', 'cadetblue', 'crimson'];
  return c; //Get a non-random color
}
}
```

without the randomization... But the return type of the function is incorrect...

Comment: So what's the criterion for choosing a colour? I.e. how do you know for a given element what the colour should be?

Comment: I would like the colors to be fixed, for example [1]=red, [2]=yellow, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set your own colors based on series order:

```
  var mycfg = {
    color: function(i) {
      c = ['red', 'yellow', 'pink', 'green', 'blue', 'olive', 'aqua', 'cadetblue', 'crimson'];
      return c[i];
    }
  }
```

The first series will be `red`, second `yellow`, etc...

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/s582jfJKLBPSKIr3HQmo?p=preview).

Comment: Should probably be `return c[i%(c.length-1)];` to avoid errors.